# How to make error message disappear after correction in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var v4 = document.f1.address.value; 
if(v4=="" || v4.trim().length==0) 
{ 
    valMessage('addressmsg','Please enter address'); 
    document.f1.address.focus(); 
    return false; 
} 

var v5 = document.f1.city.value; 
if(v5=="" || v5.trim().length==0) 
{ 
    valMessage('citymsg','Please enter your city'); 
    document.f1.city.focus(); 
    return false; 
}

function valMessage(divName, content) { 
    document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content; 
}
```

After correction error message does not dissapear. What to do?
division id given in html body dont worry about that

Comment: Are you using any kind of proxy server? Does your net console report "304 Not Modified" when it tries to download the script? It could be caching one the server, client, or somewhere in-between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show/hide your divName element, where showDiv is a boolean value (true/false):

```
function valMessage(divName, content, showDiv) { 
    document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility = showDiv ? "visible" : "hidden";
    document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content; 
}
```